# Web2py jQuery clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, web2py

I used jQuery to clone a field in a form.

```
$('#table_catalogues')
    .clone()
    .attr('id','table_catalogues_'+i2l)
    .appendTo('#table_invoices_catalogues__row')
```

But web2py doesn't create those fields, you can't see them in source
and when data is sent I find for example:

```
form.vars.catalogues = [1,2,3]
```

Actually I find that good, but having this

```
Field(
    'catalogues', 
    db.catalogues, 
    requires=IS_IN_DB(db(db.catalogues.user_id==auth.user_id)(db.catalogues.useable==True),
    'catalogues.id', 
    '%(catalogue_name)s'
),
```

is giving me trouble. When sending the form I always get this error:

> Value is not in Database

I tried to use `IS_IN_SET()` and wrote a function to export rows in a list, but I get this error:

> Value is not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the ID of a cloned object isn't enough, you need to change the name property as well. If you keep the name the same, it will overwrite the original field with the same name when the form is posted.